# Git tf alternative for Mac Os

Tags: macos, git, tfs

We want to create local repository in our company. There is a server machine (Windows). In this machine TFS integrated. Developers use Mac , as usual Xcode. We (developers) want to push/pull files from server machine. We tried Git-tf , but we couldnt integrate it with Mac OSX 10.8. Is there any alternative to Git-tf that we can push/pull files to main server? 
  Thanks in advance

Comment: To my knowledge, no, there are no other options.  What do you mean you couldn't integrate it?  What kind of problems did you have?

Comment: Do you need only git, or SVN is OK too?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @EdwardThomson I have followed the steps written in : [link] (http://www.hhogdev.com/Blog/2013/January/ios-git-tfs-integration-step-by-step.aspx) At the 5.th step I get terminal error "git: 'tf' is not a git command". I searched but did not find relevant answer. Then I have looked at the "getting started " file that has given with git-tf setup folder. It is written that it is available for macosx10.5,10.6 . We use 10.8 . This is the problem. To maxim1000 : Is SVN compatible with Mac. Svn is ok too. we can use but I dont know how?

Comment: @user2405587: that's not the problem, we test `git-tf` against 10.8.  If you get the message `'tf' is not a git command` then `git-tf` is not in your path.  Try `git-tf` instead to make sure...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I wrote a tool [SvnTfsSync](http://ficusdev.com/SvnTfsSync) for being able to work with SVN while my company uses TFS for source control. While this is not GIT, you still can benefit from it, because SVN support exists on Mac. I still use it for myself for this purpose. The tool is free.

The only downside for Mac developers is that it's not cross platform, so you will need a Windows PC to run it.

Comment: thanks a lot , we will use SVN with Tfs . I have ticked your answer.